# How can I check my RAM and hard drive for errors?

Tags: hardware, ram, disk

What tools can I use to check that my memory and hard drive are still working correctly?

Comment: Sorry, I dont know how to add comment, so I will post this as question.
(OK, I know now, I need 50 rep. points) Will `sudo /touch/forcefsck` check all my HDD's/parrtion's or just the one where Ubuntu is installed?

Comment: You misunderstood. `touch` is an application. Use `sudo touch /forcefsck`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My solution for 10.04 (That works for me):

To test RAM I'm using **Live CD 10.04**:

1. I reboot my computer with it in cd drive;
2. then I choose my language;
3. then I choose Test Ram.

For testing HDD works:

`sudo touch /forcefsck`

Found also [this tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pf7UNyZ8cXM) on youtube with additional information.

Answer (score 17):

**Boot with Ubuntu Live CD/USB stick** (or press & hold Shift before the [splash screen](http://ubuntu.hu/sites/default/files/lucid-brand-boot.png), to enter [GRUB menu](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-B0AoEoZ4qfM/T6WJZjjqrpI/AAAAAAAAANA/i4uzY9SwPAc/s320/2012-05-04+21.18.47.jpg)), and select `TEST MEMORY with memtest86+`! See this illustration, don't wait for graphical UI!

Illustration:

[image: test image]

To test HDD, you can use S.M.A.R.T. data reader, **palimpsest disk utility**, ***press Super/Dash button, start typing Disk Utility*** (for Gnome: System > Administration > Disk utility), and check your S.M.A.R.T. data (**YOU MUST UNMOUNT THAT DISK FIRST, YOU WANT TO CHECK ITS FILESYSTEM** - that's why, use a Live CD/USB stick - for S.M.A.R.T. reading, the disk could be mounted/used)!

Illustration: [image: S.M.A.R.T. DATA]

Comment: Disk Utility doesnt work for me. I get error because I use entire disk.

Comment: Hi! You say, that your root partition doesn't checkable with "Check filesystem" button?

Comment: yes I can't check it.

Comment: Yeah, you might be in a live system. Use a Live CD, and if it requires, use "Unmount Volume" button!

Comment: These are some old screenshots. Has anything changed since 2010?

Comment: I don't think so...

Answer (score 9):

For HDD, you can use `badblocks` program which is installed with the `e2fsprogs` program. It's a [command-line program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/38162/what-is-the-terminal) and a read-only scan can be performed with:

```
sudo badblocks -v /dev/sda
```

`-v` causes verbose information to be displayed, `/dev/sda` is the device name of the disk.

For RAM, you can find `memtest86+` on any live CD or USB. It'll prompt you if there's something wrong with your RAM.

Comment: I can't find badblocks in the archive

Comment: It's in `e2fsprogs` which should be installed by default.

Comment: just type `$ which badblocks` to see if you have it installed, but by sure you will.

Answer (score 8):

Hard disk:

- open up a command line, (Applications
  → Accessories → Terminal) and type

  ```
  sudo touch /forcefsck
  ```

  then reboot your computer. The
  operating system will perform a hard
  disk check (**fsck**) for you during
  the boot.

Ram:

- When the system is booting, just
  after the POST (power-on self test)
  screen, hit the ESC key a few times
  until you see the GRUB boot menu.

  You should see a list of different
  Linux kernels. Right at the bottom,
  there's an option captioned somethimg
  like **Memtest86**, this will
  thoroughly test your memory for
  corruption (also, it will take ages).

Comment: Your suggestion for hard disk work for me. Suggestion for Ram doesn't work.

Comment: what do you mean by it doesn't work?

Comment: Clarification: the "hard disk check" with `fsck` is actually a filesystem integrity check, not a hard disk surface check or something.

Answer (score 3):

Boot from an install CD, press Esc while it's booting, and you should have the option to check both memory and the hard disk.  You can do this whether or not you have Ubuntu already installed.

If you do have it installed, you can run memcheck from the grub menu.

Comment: It does - clarified.