# Windows Vista Crashing After installing via Wubi

Tags: wubi

Approximately 2 days after installing Ubuntu 11.10 through the Wubi installer while running Windows Vista (32-Bit) I have been experiencing occasional BSOD when I have my Windows OS running. Initially the first two I have no idea why my computer crashed, it was just on the desktop screen when it crashed after being left on for like 30 minutes.

The most recent BSOD was after I went to print a few documents using my printer while on Windows Vista; as a side note, my printer was also added to the Ubuntu OS before I had started printing (on the printer list). When that crash happened, the BSOD screen mentioned the saying the printer driver of my printer.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like it might be hardware related, you should test the memory/disks on your machine for errors:

- https://superuser.com/questions/155615/windows-7-x64-how-can-i-test-my-memory
- [How can I check my RAM and hard drive for errors?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14303/how-can-i-check-my-ram-and-harddrive-for-errors)

Answer (score 0):

might just be a coincidence. Check event viewer to see what's causing the BSOD.

To start Event Viewer by using the Windows interface

1. Click the Start button.
2. Click Control Panel.
3. Click System and Maintenance.
4. Click Administrative Tools.
5. Double-click Event Viewer.

To start Event Viewer by using a command line

Open a command prompt. To open a command prompt, click Start, click All Programs, click Accessories and then click Command Prompt.

Type `eventvwr`